# Firebase verify and reset password without sending separate mails

Tags: javascript, php, firebase

As part of offline user creation, I wanted to create an account from my back-end server and send out verification mail to user.
But when user clicks on the verification link, I also want to present a screen to set his password.

In the existing web-app, I have individual flows to handle verify and reset-password. but they are separate flows.

From the following [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)
I could see that there is a parameter called mode to identify the action. Using this we are currently handling the verify and reset-password actions.

But is there a way to have a custom mode or some means to identify that the user has to be taken to a different screen after verification.

One workaround I can think of is to use the continueUrl (may be with a custom scheme). Not sure if this will work flawlessly.

Can somebody share their thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `continueUrl` is indeed the correct way. Based on the `mode` you can decide which action is to be treated and then you can redirect to the `continueUrl` after the user has executed the corresponding action.

For example, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) you refer to shows the following example (note the `// TODO: If a continue URL is available...` comment):

```
function handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang) {
  // Localize the UI to the selected language as determined by the lang
  // parameter.
  // Try to apply the email verification code.
  auth.applyActionCode(actionCode).then(function(resp) {
    // Email address has been verified.

    // TODO: Display a confirmation message to the user.
    // You could also provide the user with a link back to the app.

    // TODO: If a continue URL is available, display a button which on
    // click redirects the user back to the app via continueUrl with
    // additional state determined from that URL's parameters.
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Code is invalid or expired. Ask the user to verify their email address
    // again.
  });
}
```

Comment: If I want to verify the email and reset-password using one action, I see a limitation with the actionCode (oobCode). It can't be used for both the purposes right? Can it be used?

Comment: Normally, it can’t be used for two actions since the url for each action contains a different `mode`. However, you could maybe re-build a single url that combines the different mode and oobCode values in one URL. To be tried!